Assigning a selection to a material make the mesh black
Hello I am trying to make a hoodie with a logo projected onto it. I found the method of making a new material with an image texture of a PNG. When I assign the area I want the image to be on to unwrap, it turns the material black. I would put it into the material of the hoodie with a mix color node but when I use that and export it to UE5 as a .fbx none of the colors work. I need to find a way to project the png onto the mesh and have the color underneath

The logo has a transparent background, so you'll need to specify what color you want it to be. Exporting it to UE (or even just converting it to an FBX) won't  automatically translate the Mix Color node as it is a Blender node, and requires manual adaption.

hello please pack your image and share your file
